# Defining multiple variables in python via enumeration

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a python script which does various things with 6 inputs the user gives.

Short of typing,

```
x1=input("Enter data1")

...

x6=input("Enter data6")
```

is there anyway to define these variables via some sort of index? I don't know what the code would be, but it would have the effect of the following:

Let i range from 1 to 6. Let `x_i=input("Enter Data_i")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a pythonic way you can use a dictionary for such tasks :

```
d={}
for i in range(1,7):
   d['x_{}'.format(i)]=input("Enter data{}  :".format(i))
```

Then you can get the relative values of a variable using a simple indexing.

Also you 
can use `collections.OrderedDict` to preserve the order :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> for i in range(1,7):
...    d['x_{}'.format(i)]=input("Enter data{}  :".format(i))
... 
Enter data1  :12
Enter data2  :13
Enter data3  :14
Enter data4  :15
Enter data5  :16
Enter data6  :17
>>> 
>>> d
OrderedDict([('x_1', '12'), ('x_2', '13'), ('x_3', '14'), ('x_4', '15'), ('x_5', '16'), ('x_6', '17')])
>>> 
>>> d['x_3']
'14'
```

Comment: As may be obvious, I'm new to python, but I'm left wondering why simply writing "for i in range (1,7):" and then on a new indented line "x_i=input("Enter data_i :")" doesn't work. It gets a syntax error when I run it.